Slice duration difference between reencode and codec copy
I am trying to make slices from speech segments from an audio file and merge them together.
The source audio is a single track PCM Wav file with 16Khz and 16 bits.
A slice made with -ss  -i input.wav -t  output.wav has a different duration then a slice made with -ss  -i input.wav -t  -acodec copy output.wav
To be exact:

-ss 20.125 -i input.wav -t 10.125 output-reencode.wav produces a slice with a
duration of 10s:125ms
-ss 20.125 -i input.wav -t 10.125 -acodec copy output-copy.wav produces a
slice with aduration of 10s:176ms

Why is there a 51ms difference?
Is it safe to say the reencode version is not slower because there is no compression involved with PCM?
C:\Users\someuser>ffmpeg.exe -ss 20.125 -i "C:\input.wav" -t 10.125 "C:\output-reencode.wav"
ffmpeg version 7.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
  libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
  libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
[aist#0:0/pcm_s16le @ 000001923d036b40] Guessed Channel Layout: mono
Input #0, wav, from 'C:\input.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf61.1.100
    timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Duration: 00:27:33.20, bitrate: 256 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 256 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Output #0, wav, to 'C:\output-reencode.wav':
  Metadata:
    ISMP            : 00:00:00:00
    ISFT            : Lavf61.1.100
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 256 kb/s
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavc61.3.100 pcm_s16le
[out#0/wav @ 000001923d029e80] video:0KiB audio:316KiB subtitle:0KiB other streams:0KiB global headers:0KiB muxing overhead: 0.030247%
size=     317KiB time=00:00:10.12 bitrate= 256.1kbits/s speed=1.25e+03x


C:\Users\someuser>ffmpeg.exe -ss 20.125 -i "C:\input.wav" -acodec copy -t 10.125  "C:\output-copy.wav"
ffmpeg version 7.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
  libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
  libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
[aist#0:0/pcm_s16le @ 000001ad5f9c9b80] Guessed Channel Layout: mono
Input #0, wav, from 'C:\input.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf61.1.100
    timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Duration: 00:27:33.20, bitrate: 256 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 256 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Output #0, wav, to 'C:\output-copy.wav':
  Metadata:
    ISMP            : 00:00:00:00
    ISFT            : Lavf61.1.100
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 256 kb/s
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[out#0/wav @ 000001ad5f9c9d40] video:0KiB audio:318KiB subtitle:0KiB other streams:0KiB global headers:0KiB muxing overhead: 0.030095%
size=     318KiB time=00:00:10.24 bitrate= 254.5kbits/s speed=2.76e+03x


A PCM audio stream is usually processed in frames with 1024 samples per frame.
When re-encoding with a duration specifier, ffmpeg will truncate the final frame if needed, to satisfy the duration as close as possible. When streamcopying, it will only deal in whole frames.
Your audio stream is 16000 Hz, so one frame measures 1024/16000 = 64ms. 10.125s spans 158.203125 frames. When streamcopying, the 159th frame will be full size (1024 samples), so the output duration will be 159 * 64ms = 10176ms

When you copy the audio stream, ffmpeg will only split on the keyframes. Because the keyframes aren't located on the specific timestamps you are starting and stopping from, the cut is imprecise.
When you re-encode the stream, ffmpeg doesn't care about existing keyframes as it creates new ones through the encoder.
You should be able to view the keyframe timestamps of your media file using something like ffprobe -loglevel error -skip_frame nokey -select_streams v:0 -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time -of csv=print_section=0 input.mp4
For additional information:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085458/checking-keyframe-interval
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979747/ffmpeg-how-to-trim-with-high-precision


The issue here has nothing to do with video keyframes.
